# Adding special char to regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regular expression that matches three kinds of apostrophes, `'’‘`. I directly pasted the last two from Microsoft word into the regex. However when I test it, my regular expression fails and when I inspect my javascript validation script in firefox, I see `'â€™â€˜\` instead of `'’‘`. Do I need to escape them or use the ASCII format?

Comment: Escaping won't work in this instance.  Try ASCII.

Comment: The ASCI code for one of them is &#180;. Can you show me how to do this?

Comment: This could all be lost in cut'n paste. Post the full JS test you tried that failed. `'â€™â€˜` looks like byte code.

Comment: Have you saved your script using ASCII encoding or UTF-8 encoding? Download a program like Notepad++ and change the encoding, if you are unsure. Make sure all of your files use UTF-8 encoding then add `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />` to the head of your HTML files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
/['\u2018\u2019]/
```

This matches either one of  `'’‘`.

**Explanation:**

In JavaScript regexes, `\u1234` matches the Unicode codepoint `1234`. To find out the correct codes for this special case, I copied the characters into [EditPadPro](http://www.editpadpro.com) and had it convert them into Unicode codepoints.

Comment: Some explanation would by nice. Those "try this"-answers really only give the fish, but don't show how to fish.

Answer (score 3):

Use [unicode or octal codes](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=oct):

```
/\u0022/ // matches "
/\042/ // matches "
```

Comment: Octal codes have been deprecated in the latest version of JS.